# Why does use of stdbool.h cause warning when combined with -Wtraditional-conversion

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

This is an example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void foo(bool b){};
void bar(bool b) {foo(b);}

int main() {
    bar(false);
}
```

I compile with:

```
gcc -Wtraditional-conversion test.c
```

I get these warnings:

```
test.c: In function 'bar':
test.c:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' with different width due to prototype
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'bar' with different width due to prototype
```

Why do these warnings occur? As far as I can see the arguments are all the same type, so should be the same width. What is -Wtraditional-conversion doing to cause these warnings in this very simple piece of code?

I started to get these errors when I switched from using my own typedef of bool to the stdbool.h def.

My original def was:

```
typedef enum {false, true} bool;
```

Comment: `-Wtraditional-conversion` means *Warn if a prototype causes a type conversion that is different from what would happen to the same argument in **the absence of a prototype***. You seem to be using C99, so why do you need the warning ?

Comment: what version of gcc do you have?

Comment: @JensGustedt gcc (Gentoo 4.4.3-r2 p1.2) 4.4.3

Comment: @cnicutar I probably don't need the warning. I did not specify the compiler flags, that was some one else. You may of answered the question by pointing out it is probably not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a case of not understanding the compiler warning flags.

Use `-Wconversion` not `-Wtraditional-conversion` to get warnings that warn about implicit conversion. `-Wtraditional-conversion` is for warning about conversions in the absence of a prototype.

Was caught out because the `typdef enum` creates a default integer bool type (32bit normally), where as `stdbool.h` defines bool as an 8bit, which is compatible with the C++ bool.

Answer (score 0):

The warning for the call to `bar` is correct, since you ask the compiler to be pendantic. `false` expands to the `int` constant `0`, so it is not a `bool` (or `_Bool`).

The first warning is a bug.